# Best options for disk or file mirror without shutting down machine

Tags: disk, mirroring, cloning

I'm looking for some good options for mirroring or cloning my disk without shutting the machine down. In the past all the options I've looked at are very expensive (usually several thousands).

Hoping to find something that works for Windows (2003 and 2008) and Linux.

Hoping to spend up to a few hundred, definitely not thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, for Hyper-V 2012, that replication and automatic failover come as part of the package.

I wasn't aware that Microsoft had this functionality. I'll be giving it a try over the next few weeks to see how it goes.